# I can't get data from JSON with python

Tags: python, json, api, get

I can't seem to get the last recorded price from a website API using JSON. I tried finding the error but it seems okay to me. The code is in python
This is the Url that I have to GET: https://api.independentreserve.com/Public/GetMarketSummary?primaryCurrencyCode=xbt&secondaryCurrencyCode=aud

Python 3.7

```
import requests


URL = "https://api.independentreserve.com/Public/GetMarketSummary?"

CurrencyCode = "xbt"
SecondaryCode = "aud"
PARAMS = {'primaryCurrencyCode': CurrencyCode, '&secondaryCurrencyCode': SecondaryCode}
r = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)

data = r.json()


lastprice = data['LastPrice']


print("Last Price:%s" % lastprice)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the fixed code

```
import requests


URL = "https://api.independentreserve.com/Public/GetMarketSummary?"

CurrencyCode = "xbt"
SecondaryCode = "aud"
PARAMS = {'primaryCurrencyCode': CurrencyCode, 'SecondaryCurrencyCode': SecondaryCode}
r = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)

data = r.json()


lastprice = data['LastPrice']


print("Last Price:%s" % lastprice)
```

the problem is in the `PARAMS` dict. you need to change `"&secondaryCurrencyCode"` to `"SecondaryCurrencyCode"`.

if you had printed the `data` dict, you would see this:

`{'Message': 'Secondary Currency Code is required'}`

Answer (score 0):

Removing `&` in `"&secondaryCurrencyCode"` will fix the issue.

Fixed code below:

```
import requests

URL = "https://api.independentreserve.com/Public/GetMarketSummary?"

CurrencyCode = "xbt"
SecondaryCode = "aud"
PARAMS = {'primaryCurrencyCode': CurrencyCode, 'secondaryCurrencyCode': SecondaryCode}
r = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)

data = r.json()


lastprice = data['LastPrice']

print("Last Price:%s" % lastprice)
```

Answer (score 0):

API is expecting `secondaryCurrencyCode` not `&secondaryCurrencyCode`.

You don't need & sign when you use params.